MongoDB Indexes unexpectedly getting removed automatically , NestJS
I'm facing an odd situation where I try to create Index(regular, compoud) on a field/fields, and they are automatically removed, and the mongodb hint()  throws the error

Collation: { locale: "simple" }  planner returned error :: caused by
:: hint provided does not correspond to an existing index

I have two fields on which I want to put index
  @Prop({ required: true, type: ProductSubset, default: null })
  reviewedItem: ProductSubset;

  @Prop({ required: false, min: 0, default: 0 })
  rating: number;

Index Creation
MySchema.index({ 'reviewedItem._id': 1, rating: 1 }, { unique: true });

OR
MySchema.index({ 'reviewedItem._id': 1 }, { unique: true });

OR
MySchema.index({ 'rating': 1 }, { unique: true });

OR
export const MySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Class).index(
  { 'reviewedItem._id': 1, rating: 1 },
  { unique: true },
);

Two Conditions I faced
1- When I create the index, and goes to mongdb compass, and goes to Indexes section of the collection, I finds the index created there, but when I refresh 3,4 times SIZE OF THE INDEX AUTOMATICALLY INCREASES AND WHEN REACHES ROUND ABOUT 4MBS it suddenly gets removed.
2- In case where I don't REFRESH THE COMPASS, the index is removed automatically when I request the endpoint.Where I face the Error hint provided does not correspond to an existing index
MY MONGODB VERSION IS 6.0.5 AND NEST JS VERSION IS ABOVE 9
Mongodb Log File : These are the two last logs I found
Second Last Log
"attr": {
    "code": "BABEL_PARSE_ERROR",
    "reasonCode": "MissingSemicolon",
    "loc": {
      "line": 1,
      "column": 2,
      "index": 2
    },
    "pos": 2,
    "message": "Missing semicolon. (1:2)\n\n\u001b[0m\u001b[31m\u001b[1m>\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[90m 1 |\u001b[39m cd nano  \u001b[33m/\u001b[39m\u001b[36mvar\u001b[39m\u001b[33m/\u001b[39mlog\u001b[33m/\u001b[39mmongodb\u001b[33m/\u001b[39mmongod\u001b[33m.\u001b[39mlog\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m   |\u001b[39m   \u001b[31m\u001b[1m^\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 2 |\u001b[39m\u001b[0m",
    "name": "SyntaxError",
    "stack": "SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:2)\n\n\u001b[0m\u001b[31m\u001b[1m>\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[90m 1 |\u001b[39m cd nano  \u001b[33m/\u001b[39m\u001b[36mvar\u001b[39m\u001b[33m/\u001b[39mlog\u001b[33m/\u001b[39mmongodb\u001b[33m/\u001b[39mmongod\u001b[33m.\u001b[39mlog\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m   |\u001b[39m   \u001b[31m\u001b[1m^\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 2 |\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\n"
  }

Last log
"msg": "Flushed outstanding data",
  "attr": {
    "flushError": null,
    "flushDuration": 0
  }

ALSO I'M RUNNING A REPLICA SET OF DB

I don't think there's really enough information to troubleshoot the problem. I'd recommend pulling the MongoDB log file and looking for entries related to indexing.

@user20042973 What information you require?.By the way I'm running a replica of db,could that some how be issue?

@user20042973 I checked my log files.and I found something that might help. I've updated my question kindly have a look.
